# After new version is updated using WinSparkle it doesn't launch app automatically

Tags: c++, qt5, sparkle

I'm using [WinSparkle](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle) (latest version 0.5.3) framework in my Qt C++ app for auto-update. It works perfectly with detecting new version, downloading and installing the new version automatically.

But I found after the new version is installed, it doesn't launch the app automatically, and users have to launch it manually.

I checked the [WinSparkle API reference](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle/blob/master/include/winsparkle.h), but didn't find any settings related to this. I think it should have built-in support for auto-launching the app after update?

Is there a way in [WinSparkle](https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle) to handle it in the same way as [Sparkle](https://sparkle-project.org/) does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my answer from this Github issue: https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle/issues/132

Bascially WinSparkle cannot do this at the moment, we should implement the auto-launching function in the Windows app installer itself.

But it would be nice to allow WinSparkle to update from a ZIP file, and then take the control of launching app automatically after update. Any relevant PRs are welcome.